# row space and kernel of a matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a real $m \times n$ matrix $A$ and vectors $x,z \in R^n$ how can I show that

$x \in \ker{A} \wedge x^Tz = 0   \quad \Rightarrow \quad \exists y \in R^m : z = A^Ty $ ?

I thought to start with
$Ax= 0$ and left multiply each side by a vector $ y \in R^m$ to obtain $y^TAx= 0$. The equation is now scalar and we can transpose both sides into $x^TA^Ty= 0$. Now I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that $z\in \text{Im}(A^T)$. Recall that $\ker(A)=\text{Im}(A^T)^{\perp}$. Hence $x\in \text{Im}(A^T)^{\perp}$. Since $x^Tz=0$, $\left\langle x,z\right\rangle =0$, so $x\perp z$. Hence $z\in (\text{Im}(A^T)^{\perp})^{\perp}=\text{Im}(A^T)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a more general approach, in addition to the answer given.

Let $\mathcal{R}(A^T), \mathcal{N}(A)$ denote the row space and the nullspace of $A$, respectively.

We already know that the $2$ subspaces $\mathcal{N}(A)$ and $\mathcal{R}(A^T)$ are orthogonal. But it's not just that. $\mathcal{N}(A)$ and $\mathcal{R}(A^T)$ are orthogonal complements, according to the [Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra), so we can say that: $$\big(\mathcal{N}(A)\big)^\perp = \mathcal{R}(A^T).$$

In short, the above states that *whatever is orthogonal to the nullspace $\mathcal{N}(A)$, then it must belong to the row space*.

---

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}(A)}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathcal{R}(A^T)}$

The nullspace $\N$ includes all the vectors $x$ such that $Ax = 0$. Assume that there is a $z$, such that $z \perp \N$, but $z \notin \R$. Adding the vector $z$ as a last row of the matrix $A$ yields:
$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 
row \, 1 \\
row \, 2\\
\vdots\\
row \, m \\
coordinates \,of\, vector \, z
\end{bmatrix}}_{(m+1)\times n} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2 \\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
The fundamental theorem of Linear Algebra states:

> $$\dim \N + \dim \R = n.$$

We have to notice that although we modified the matrix $A$, $\N$ didn't change at all! $\N$ includes exactly the same vectors as before. Also, $n$ is the same as before.

This implies that $\dim\R$ must be the same as before, which means that $z \in \R$.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that I want to prove that $\ker{A}$ and $im A^T$ are orthogonal complement.

It is easy to see that these spaces are orthogonal. Indeed if $z \in im A^T$ then we can write 
$z = A^T y$ and it follows $z \perp x, \ \forall x \in \ker A$, that is $z^T x = y^T A x = 0$.

Now from the fundamental theorem I can't understand why these two orthogonal spaces are complement of each other, that is my original question: why if a vector is orthogonal to  $\ker{A}$ it must lie on  $im A^T$ and vice versa?

An example: consider three dimensional euclidean space (x,y,z). Consider the subspaces y=x and y=-x. They are orthogonal but not complement of each other because any vector on the z axis (x=y=0) is orthogonal to vectors on y=x but they don't lie on y=-x.

Comment: Answer edited..

Comment: thanks! I can't vote your answer due to low reputation, anyway it complitely solved my doubts.

Comment: You are welcome. It's alright!  Just something more... If you want to add extra content in your question, you can edit the question and add anything you like, including e.g. extra thoughts.